# Ansible Module oracle_user does not set password as set up in vault

Tags: ansible

we just using ansible to automate creation of databases.
In my actual issue i wanted to set up databases and users in 19c PDB Environment
database setu woks fine. Creation of the Application specific users also reports no error
but
the Password is not set up as expected in our database vault. If setting password on hand it works fine

Task for User creaion:

```
- name: create deploy user DPLUS_%
  connection: local
  no_log: true
  oracle_user:
    hostname:                "{{ db_hostname }}"
    service_name:            "{{ rcs_pdb_service }}"
    user:                    "{{ db_connect_user }}"
    password:                "{{ db_connect_password }}"
    mode:                    "{{ db_connect_mode }}"
    schema:                  "{{ item.username }}"
    schema_password:         "{{ item.password_vault }}"
    default_tablespace:      "{{ rcs_db_deploy_default_tablespace }}"
    default_temp_tablespace: "{{ rcs_db_deploy_temporary_tablespace }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ rcs_db_deploy_users }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

Entries in PW Vault like this:

```
  - username: DPLUS_APPL
    password_hash: S:ABDED382253DB7932BCBCC93C6D3B6E742B664C5D9F1E737D5AB373714D8;T:89F040CEB67D2AD5B57DC0C8B62B60C308F9A10BEA45E0081FB6C70D664D6AFE584E67022A501C679CE8A78968A5F7F63359690728B27C92C33AEE77D0FCCCFAEA0E6DF37A46AEDC3B41BB04393BC755
    password_vault: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      66326561616635303135306638333136643532363533376234633932303833316230653164353234
      3765373433633836643631343035643539313838303063630a376465393635356663393338626632
      61306135303363623038656562353939356465396331373466323131633434373832666363323436
      6534613839373966300a613838613731616465633931323164343464316264613233366562653662
      6631
```

We just checked the password with ansible-vault view ... and the passowrd is as expected.
But Login into database failed with ora-1017

any hints ?
thanks
Uwe

- running code as yaml playbook OK but PWs are not correct
- checking the ansible vault with ansible-vault OK
- running block for setting passwords manually with oracle_sql - OK, but unsafe

Expecting corect passwords to be set by ansible playbook

The vault is created ages ago, but it works for all eenvironemts except the CDB/PDB environment. Standalone Environments with one Db on one host works fine on AWS and on inhouse VMs.
We just encrypted the pw and it was fine as we expect.
Just set a new pw for vault : dsafjlkAS_Dfdsaf_sdaf--dsaf987

Comment: Without the password for your current vault, no one can test if the the content is effectively correct. Either give the password of the above vault if possible or create a new [mre] with totally dummy passwords with which you can reproduce the problem on your side and we can use to try to reproduce on our side. While you're at it, you must describe precisely how you create the vault string and how you checked it to conclude that "it's ok". Please do not try to add any of those information in comments: [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

We found the error. There was a newline running into the vault for all PWs. After deleting all worked fine